# Two op amps from a single input voltage

Tags: arduino

I have an output of an LM741 of +-2.5V, I have two more LM741's I wish to take this signal into an arduino due, once with a range of 0-3.3v to get a wide span and then chop the peak off the original signal (+2V to +2.5V) and convert this into 0-3.3V for accuracy.
I've tried rectifying it just to look at the 0-2.5V but I need more resolution at the peak voltage input, when I put the op-amp on the voltage on the original signal changes.

Comment: Are you just asking for a circuit which can take an input of -2.5V to +2.5V and convert it to 0 to 3.3V?

Comment: What power supply voltages are you using to power the 741s? They simply will not work properly with a single 5 volt supply.

Comment: I have +-5V power supplies.
I want a signal for -2.5V to +2.5V to convert it to 0 to 3.3V and another for +2V to +2.5V to convert it to 0 to 3.3V.

Answer (score 1):

First, get a different op anp. The 741 is designed to work from +/- 15 volts, and is not specified for anything else. As an example, at +/- 15 volts the output swing for a 2k load is only guaranteed to be +/- 10 volts. So if 5 volts is the difference between the supply and the maximum load output, for a +/- 5 volts supply the output may only provide +/- 0 volts. That said, the following should work if you use the right op amps

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fz3gIb.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Also, it assumes your -5 is quiet, stable and accurate.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a go. I'm using a switching power supply I've already got capacitors to reduce the noise.